# PHP session expiring too early

Tags: php, expired-sessions

I have an issue, my apps sessions are expiring unexpectedly after about 15 minutes. I need them to expire after 4 hours.

The server is Centos 5.5, PHP is 5.3.2.

Below is my code (included in an global header).

```
<?php
session_name('MobileSuiteHQ');
if(!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 14400000);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 14400000);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 1000);
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 0);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
ini_set('session.name','MobileSuiteHQ');
?>
```

My .htaccess file contains:

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 14400000
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 14400000
php_value session.use_cookies 0
php_value session.gc_divisor 1000
```

Any help or insight would be greatful.

EDIT: I was unable to login when i updated my .htaccess file, the session wasn't starting. So I have now removed:

```
php_value session.use_cookies 0
```

which now allows me to login.

Comment: Is the cookie coming in with the request?  Is the session dying on the client end, or the server end?

Comment: But sessions do work in general, right?

Comment: @profitphp: The use of cookies for the session ID is disabled (see *session.use\_cookies*).

Comment: Ok then, is the request coming through with the PHP session ID query string parameter? Is the session dying on the client end, or the server end?

Comment: Are you sure your php / apache is configured to read .htaccess files and set variables via ini_set()?

Comment: @profitphp: phpsessid is not present in the url

Comment: @jacobangel: It is set to read .htaccess and vars via ini_set, i can see the values in a phpinfo() dump.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On initial examination, I'd lower your gc_maxlifetime and cookie_lifetime settings. I suspect that 14400000 is a little high for PHP to cope with (in theory, a 32-bit OS should be able to go up to 2147483647, but this could still be a factor).

If you only need 4 hours of lifetime, then 14400 would be a perfect setting, and may resolve your problem for the reason mentioned above.

Comment: 14400000 is 4 hours in milliseconds. I will lower it to see if it helps, also server is 64bit.

Comment: Yep, but the cookie_lifetime is expecting a value in seconds :)

Answer (score 8):

I dont know about CentOS, but on Ubuntu the php5 package installs a /etc/cron.d/php5 file that'll remove 'untouched for 24min' session files on the :9 and :39 of every hour. So you have a minimum of 24min and max of 54min sessions.

Comment: Thank you Nate, we changed to an mysql session solution.

Answer (score 0):

**
create some ajax code that does a request every 10 minutes
var refreshTime = 600000; // every 10 minutes in milliseconds**

```
window.setInterval( function() {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        url: "refreshSession.php",
        success: function(data) {
        }
    });
}, refreshTime );
```

Comment: thanks for the reply however this post is over 10 years old.