# Keeping sessions alive for specific time

Tags: php, session

I am building a site with a shopping cart which is stored in sessions like this:

```
if (!array_key_exists($pid, $_SESSION['cart'])) 
    {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$pid] = array(
            'itemId'=>$pid,
            'qty'=>0
        );  
    }
```

The issue is that the Sessions are expiring quickly, maybe 30 minutes. I would like to be able to keep the sessions for 1 day at least.

Is there any specific way for doing this?

Comment: I've always used this method and found it to be fine! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes

Comment: You can check this link. Same issue like yours.


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936207/php-session-expiring-too-early

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to extend the session by editing the following in php.ini:

; After this number of seconds, stored data will be seen as 'garbage' and
; cleaned up by the garbage collection process.
; http://php.net/session.gc-maxlifetime

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
```